# indexOf failing to recognize word

Tags: javascript, jquery, indexof

Unsure why indexOf is not recognizing the word 'error'.

The PHP script is returning text that reads:

```
echo "Error: user was not updated.";
```

In the JQuery, I have the following:

```
$.post('api/editUser.php', {robj:robj}, function(data){
  if(data.indexOf('Error')){
    console.log("bad - " + data);
  }
  else{
    console.log("good - " + data);
  }
});
```

Using the above, I keep getting the output "good - Error: user was not updated"

The console should be reading: "bad - Error: user was not updated"

Is the problem with indexOf?

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: try to `console.log(data.indexOf)`.

Comment: Have you tried debugging this? I think you are missing a proper condition in that `if` statement, as `indexOf` returns an integer, not a boolean

Comment: probably since it's the first word, `indexOf` return `0` which is treated as `false` in your condition. `indexOf` returns `-1` if the substring doesn't appear in the string

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`indexOf` returns `0` because your word is placed as first word in string. Zero is `falsy` value, so try to rewrite to check `indexoOf() != -1`:

```
if( data.indexOf('Error')!= -1){
   console.log("bad - " + data);
}
else{
   console.log("good - " + data);
```

[As mdn says:](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/indexOf)

> The indexOf() method returns the first index at which a given element
> can be found in the array, or -1 if it is not present.

Answer (score 1):

If you try to log the `indexOf` return you'll see it returns `0`

```js
console.log( "Error: user was not updated.".indexOf("Error") )
```

then doing `if (0)` you see that you get into the `else` block

```js
if (0) {console.log("in if")} else {console.log("in else")}
```

This happens because `0` is a [`falsy value`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Glossary/Falsy), meaning a value which is considered as a `false` when coersing to a boolean

---

To get what you wanted you can either use `indexOf === 0` if any message with `"Error"` not at the start is a valid message, or `includes` if any message containing `"Error"` is invalid no matter it's possition

```js
console.log( "Error: user was not updated.".indexOf("Error") === 0 )
console.log( "Error: user was not updated.".includes("Error") )
console.log( "message with Error at the center".indexOf("Error") === 0 )
console.log( "message with Error at the center".includes("Error") )
```

Answer (score 0):

Try using `search()`. It's mostly used for regular expressions, but if you use a plain text it will still work since it will be a valid Regular Expression.
Please note that it's not as performant as `indexOf`, since it's treated as a **RegEx**.

P.s. I know you know the exact text that is coming from the server, but it's always safer to make everything lowercased, for consistency.

This should work:

```js
$.post('api/editUser.php', {robj:robj}, function(data){
  if(data.toLowerCase().search('error')){
    console.log("bad - " + data);
  }
  else{
    console.log("good - " + data);
  }
});
```